# When/Why To Use A Entity Key Type Serializable

Tags: java, key, entity, repository-pattern, dao

### Preface

I have been doing some research about Data Access Objects and the Repository pattern with the goal of implementing a reasonably robust interface to persistent storage in my application. While reading, I could swear I saw something about using the type Serializable for the primary key in entity classes. This notion intrigues me since I believe every underlying storage mechanism's keys are probably serializable. By making an id field type Serializable, my intuition tells me I could reuse my domain objects across multiple storage APIs more easily (if only I could wrap my head around the concept!)

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to backtrack to where I (think I) read about this, and Google is too busy giving me tutorials on how to make objects serializable or how to use the Serial Version Id.

### The Question

Is it sensible to use the type Serializable for the key in an entity class? Are there any open source examples of such an implementation? Any pros/cons?